# FBA Authentication with Custom Database

Tags: authentication, forms-authentication

I want to implement forms based authentication for a sharepoint portal. I have used the standard ASP.NET membership provider database for test purpose and it work fine.

My client has Authentication details on their own SQL Database and I want to implement FBA that uses the custom database to authenticate users.

Does any one have any suggestions on how to implement this. Do I need to write a custom authentication provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the schema of custom DB is same as **aspnetDB**, You can use the same provider with relevant  *connectionString* in the central admin and the web application config.You can  provide userid\pwd in the *connectionString* as below:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="MySqlConnection" connectionString="Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;Integrated Security=SSPI;User ID=myDomain\myUsername; Password=myPassword;" />
</connectionStrings>
<system.web>
...
  <membership defaultProvider="SqlProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
    <providers>
      <clear />
      <add 
        name="SqlProvider" 
        type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" 
        connectionStringName="MySqlConnection"
        applicationName="MyApplication"
        enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
        enablePasswordReset="true"
        requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true"
        requiresUniqueEmail="true"
        passwordFormat="Hashed" />
    </providers>
  </membership>
```

Comment: Hi Amit, the schema is different

Comment: Then you have to build a custom provider. This may be helpful : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165159/Custom-Membership-Providers

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at SharePoint 2010 FBA Pack:

http://sharepoint2010fba.codeplex.com/

A forms based authentication pack for SharePoint 2010. It includes web parts for registering users, changing passwords and password recovery. It includes tools for managing users and roles and for approving registrations.

Comment: Hi Ashish, Does this work with custom database?

Comment: Yes, check the documentation - http://sharepoint2010fba.codeplex.com/documentation and follow the first link.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create you own MembershipProvider implementation since you are not going to use the default FBA database, but a custom database instead.
It is not such a difficult to implement your own.
check out these link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e.aspx

Comment: Creating custom membership is tricky. On the paper seems easy, but you really need to know what you do. But that's the way you should follow.